# Binding child views and collections within an outlet in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to render a view `Team` inside of an `{{outlet}}`.  This `Team` view is comprised of a simple `Person` view (the team leader), and a collection of `Person` views (team members).  The outlet is set up by calling `connectOutlet()` on the ApplicationController.

Although the `Person` child views are rendered in the markup as expected, all the values of `name` are missing.  It sure seems like my bindings and/or controller are not set up properly.  What am I missing?

Code and demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aek38/fkKFJ/

The relevant handlebar templates are:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="app">
    <div class="container">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="person">
    <em>Person name is:</em> {{name}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="team">
    <h3>Team Leader</h3>
    <em>Leader name should be:</em>{{leader.name}}
    {{view App.PersonView contentBinding="leader"}}
    <h3>Team Members</h3>
    {{#collection contentBinding="members"}}
        {{view App.PersonView contentBinding="content"}}
    {{/collection}}
</script>
```

Code snippet:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
ready: function() {
    this.initialize();
},
ApplicationController: Ember.Controller.extend(),
ApplicationView: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "app"
}),

Person: Ember.Object.extend({
    name: "Jane Doe"
}),
PersonController: Ember.ObjectController.extend(),
PersonView: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "person"
}),

Team: Ember.Object.extend({
    members: [],
    leader: null
}),
TeamController: Ember.ObjectController.extend(),
TeamView: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "team"
}),
// ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
{{view App.PersonView contextBinding="leader"}}
```

and use `{{#each}}` instead of `{{#collection}}` for the members

http://jsfiddle.net/LQTsV/1/

Comment: Aha, thanks!  I needed to use *context*, not _content_.  One character makes all the difference in the world (as it always does).

Comment: Why use {{each}} over {{collection}}?  My impression was that both are ok, but admittedly I can't tell whether {{collection}} is officially recommended anymore and/or will survive in ember's future.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure whats going on but I tweaked your fiddle to get it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/lifeinafolder/sPcwv/

Seems as if bindings are not working properly in the sense:

> contentBinding="this"

works but

> contentBinding="this.leader"

doesn't.

Sorry but I couldn't work it out more.

Comment: Also noticed that you are using ember-latest and handlebars beta. Have you tried with old more stable versions?

Comment: I like to live dangerously.  No, actually, I wanted to use connectOutlets on my routes, which is not available in 0.9.8.1 yet.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `content` variable on person view via `contentBinding` that should probably be `personBinding`. And then in your template you should get the `view.person.name`.

`{{collection}}` should be a `{{each}}` block.

```
{{#each members}}
    {{view App.PersonView personBinding="this"}}
{{/each}}
```

And this person template will look in the right location for the name.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="person">
    <em>Person name is:</em> {{view.person.name}}
</script>
```

Didn't change your js.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/albertjan/fkKFJ/9/