# Emberjs child view binding

Tags: ember.js

I have the following container

```
script type: 'text/x-handlebars', 'data-template-name': 'application', ->
text '''
{{outlet}}      
'''
```

Then this view is connected to it

```
script type: 'text/x-handlebars', 'data-template-name': 'index', ->
text '''
{{view App.SignUpView}}
'''
```

The actual view

```
App.SignUpView = Ember.View.extend
templateName: 'signup'

isValid: true
email: ''
password: ''
```

Template:

```
script type: 'text/x-handlebars', 'data-template-name': 'signup', ->
text '''
  is valid: {{isValid}}
'''
```

How can I bind the isValid field to the view? It is undefined. Is that somehow related to the "outlet" in the parent view?

This example [Binding child views and collections within an outlet in emberjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643426/binding-child-views-and-collections-within-an-outlet-in-emberjs) shows how to bind an arbitrary object to the view.

Comment: related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818116/ember-js-handlebars-displays-nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the view scope in your template:

```
is valid: {{view.isValid}}
```

Comment: glad I can help :-) Is it a correct answer for you? If so, you can accept it.